# Minified React Error #321 with Docusaurus v2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, docusaurus

I am trying to deploy Docusaurus v2 and I keep getting this error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...

√ Client
  Compiled successfully in 18.44s

× Server
  Compiled with some errors in 20.74s
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
...
...
...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! website@0.0.0 deploy: `docusaurus deploy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I am working in a team, everyone is working off the same repo, and `deploy` seems to work for most people. The error-decoder link suggests it could be:

1. Mismatching versions of React and React-dom.
2. Breaking the Rules of Hooks.
3. More than one copy of React in the same app.

I tried updating everything including React and react-dom.

I don't see how it could be 2 or 3 given it works for most people. Everything runs fine locally. Any suggestions on what to try in order to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - I had tinkered with the default `const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();` in `index.js`, moving it out of the function.

Worked once I moved it back into the function.

<sub>(might not help you since you say it works for some people, but hey, worked for me!)</sub>